# post с параметром body в android

Tags: android, post, retrofit

Всем привет. Прошу указать в чем моя ошибка. И так. Отправляю post запрос с параметром body. Приложение выводит в тост "Ошибка на сервере" из onResponce.

Вот код запроса

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RegistrationUserAPI registrationUserAPI = retrofit.create(RegistrationUserAPI.class);
            RegistrationUserBody registrationUserBody = new RegistrationUserBody();
            registrationUserBody.name = stringNameActivityRegistration;
            registrationUserBody.email = stringEmailActivityRegistration;
            registrationUserBody.password = stringPasswordActivityRegistration;
            registrationUserBody.contactNumber = stringContactNumberActivityRegistration;
            Call<RegistrationUserBody> call = registrationUserAPI.registrationUser(registrationUserBody);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationUserBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Response<RegistrationUserBody> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Запрос выполнен успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка на сервере", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка во время выполнения запроса", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Интерфейс

```
public  interface RegistrationUserAPI {
@POST("/api/users")
Call<RegistrationUserBody> registrationUser(@Body RegistrationUserBody 
registrationUserBody);
```

}

Параметр (тело) запроса

```
public class RegistrationUserBody {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
String name;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
String password;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
String email;

@SerializedName("contact_number")
@Expose
String contactNumber;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
```

}

P.S перед тем как задавать вопрос пытался найти похожий, не безрезультатно

Comment: В `onResponse` вам вторым параметром возвращается `response`, так что смотрите внимательно в нём на значения `body`/`errorBody` в зависимости от того, отработал запрос успешно или нет соответственно. Там должен быть ответ на ваш вопрос, что именно не так в теле запроса

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите в классе **RegistrationUserBody** метод **toString**. Т.к. ретрофит приводит Ваш класс к строке для передачи его на сервер. Это можно сделать к примеру вот так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```